# Create new objects in a scene from point locations?

Tags: geometry-nodes, point-clouds

I'm using Geometry Nodes to generate a set of points within the volume of a mesh (a human character in this case), with the hope that I can take these points, export them into Unity, and use them as empty GameObjects to attach things to.

The point generation works great and does exactly what I need. What I can't figure out is an automatic way to use the points to create new Emptys inside my Blender scene, which can then be easily exported to Unity. I'm able to do it manually, but it requires me converting all the points to cubes, splitting them to separate objects, centering the pivots, and deleting the geometry.

Is there any way to directly hook up the position data from my Geometry Nodes points to new separate Empty objects in my Blender scene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean something like this ... *Cube* with *Empties* - enable **As Instance** under Object Info node ...

[image]
[image]

To realise instances ...

You can Ctrl+A > **Make Instances Real**, which will create individual *Empty* objects at those points (the GN object will still be there, modifier still on it, it won't be applied).
(Credit goes to Kuboå :) I just wanted to highlighted his comment here.)

I exported object with GN modifier as Alembic (.abc) and Imported back. Realised Empties come as parented to the Cube object that is now just an container without any vertex.

Comment: You can *Ctrl+A* > *Make Instances Real*, which will create individual Empty objects at those points (the GN object will still be there, modifier still on it, it won't be applied).

Comment: Do you want o create an answer? I'm ready to delete it :)

Comment: Nah, just incorporate it into yours so it's complete :)

Comment: This works great, thanks both of you!

Answer (score 3):

The *old* Blender way :

Parent an empty to your point cloud object (With <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + drag in the outliner or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), enable vertex instancing in the point cloud object, Make instances real.

[image]